# PHP, SQL как из готовых данных сделать массив с подмассивом?

Tags: php, sql, массивы, push

Я делаю запрос в бд

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users`
```

Так же есть пустой массив

```
$array = Array();
```

Т.е с бд я получаю несколько строк к примеру, и каждая строка имеет столбец `id` и `name`.
Как мне в массив `$array` засунуть элементом `id`, а `name` в виде подмассива элемента `id` ?
Пример:
т.е получить
3(id) - элемент и подмассив этого элемента Mikle(name).

Comment: приведите пример массива, чтоб понять структуру

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users`");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $array = Array();
    while ($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $array = array_merge($array, $item);
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]